# How to get content inside shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to get content inside my shortcode in a wordpress site. I tried to do it by this code but didn't work.

```
<?php $content= get_the_content(); ?> <?php echo do_shortcode('[goo-pie-chart data="$content"]'); ?>
```

Comment: What's your Output?

Comment: It shows nothing

Comment: Did You Tried `<?php echo do_shortcode('[goo-pie-chart data="'.$content.'"]'); ?>` .?

Comment: Yes, it displayed the content but some css issues are seen which I'll manage. Thank You very much.

Comment: Since my content is in unicode, I need to get rid of special characters and <br>. How to remove it from the content?

Comment: try `the_content()`